# Atiyah Macdonald Nilradical/Jacobson Radical Proof Verification

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am reviewing some old problems from Atiyah MacDonald Chapter 1, in particular problem 6. I was reviewing a proof that I found in [this](https://dangtuanhiep.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/papaioannoua_solutions_to_atiyah.pdf) solution manual. I have some questions regarding minute details on the validity of this proof. I will reproduce the question and the solution below to keep the question self contained.

6. A ring $A$ is such that every ideal not contained in the nilradical contains a non-zero idempotent (an element $e$ such that $e = e^2 \neq 0$). Prove that the nilradical and Jacobson radical are equal.

Solution 6 from online manual) It clearly suffices to show that every prime ideal in $A$ is maximal. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $A$ and let $x$ be a non-zero element of $A-\mathfrak{p}$. Then the ideal $\langle x \rangle$ will contain an idempotent element $e \neq 0$, say $a_0x$. This implies that $a_0x(a_x-1) = 0 \in \mathfrak{p}$, so $a_0x(a_0x-1) = 0$ in $A/\mathfrak{p}$ too. However, $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is an integral domain, therefore $e = a_0x \neq 0$ implies $a_0x = 1$, thus $x$ is a unit, hence $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field.

My questions about the proof are:

1. Does the $x$ we invoke need also be a non-unit since otherwise $\langle x \rangle = A$? However, if no such non-unit exists then $\mathfrak{p}$ would already be maximal?
2. The proof relies on the $a_0x \neq 0$ in $A/\mathfrak{p}$ which is iff $a_0x \notin \mathfrak{p}$ but can we be sure $a_ox \notin \mathfrak{p}$ just because $x \notin \mathfrak{p}$?
3. Assuming the logic questioned in 2 is valid, is the arbitrary $x \notin \mathfrak{p}$ being a unit in the quotient sufficient? It seems to me this would say that all the non units in $A$ correspond to units in the quotient, but then units always correspond to units also?

Comment: This proof is indeed flawed, as you correctly identified in 2 (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4005276))

Comment: An explicit example of a reduced ring with this property that is not zero-dimensional can be found after Proposition 1.9 in the classic paper [Lifting Idempotents and Exchange Rings](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1977-229-00/S0002-9947-1977-0439876-2/S0002-9947-1977-0439876-2.pdf). (Briefly: this is the set of rational sequences which are eventually a constant integer)